# PHP Session expire event

Tags: php, session

I am trying to make some changes to an opensource project. I want to keep track of when users log in and log out. 
Right now I change their login status in db when they login or manually log out. The problem right now is that I cannot find out if the user just closed their browser without pressing on logout button. 
For this reason I need to trigger a function that will change database every time the user's session expires.
I've tried `session_set_save_handler` in PHP, but it looks like I need to override the whole session behavior. What I am looking for is to keep default session behavior and just add functionality when the user's session expires. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something *really* nasty once. Every time a session was "updated" by a page refresh / fetch / etc., I updated a timestamp on a DB row. A second daemon polled the DB every 10 minutes and performed "clean-up" operations.

You won't find any native PHP facilities to achieve your goal. Session timeout doesn't run in the background. You won't even know if a session is timed out, unless a timed out session attempts another access. At this point, nearly impossible to trap, you can make your determination and handle it appropriately.

I'd recommend a queue & poll architecture for this problem. It's easy and will definitely work. Add memcached if you have concerns about transaction performance.

Comment: I have done something similar.  I made a function that would both update a users recent page/activity AND poll the database looking for inactive sessions greater than 2 minutes and would purge them.  Figured I could kill 2 birds with one stone.  Messy, but got the job done without having to create a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using standard PHP file-based sessions. If that's the case, then PHP will do its own garbage collection of stale sessions based on the session.gc_* configuration parameters in php.ini. You can override those to disable the garbage collector completely, then roll your own GC script.

You could either check the timestamps on the files (quick and easy to do in a loop with stat()) to find 'old' sessions, or parse the data in each file to check for a variable that lists the last-access time. Either way, the session files are merely the output of `serialize($_SESSION)` and can be trivially re-loaded into another PHP instance.

Answer (score -1):

What about window close event on javascript. So basically session is destroyed when all of the windows of the session site are closed. So, when the last window is closed ( this is checked via additional js checking ) send ajax request to server.

Comment: Good idea, however just because you close a window doesn't mean the session is over, they could keep the browser open and reload the webpage and they would still be using their original session.  Not only that, but leaving one webpage for another on the same domain would fire the ajax event that removes session info from the database while they are still visiting the site.  If there was a javascript event to check for browser closing, that would be better.