# Storing all user activity as session values and saving session values at the end of session

Tags: php, events, session, event-handling

Normally, I would save all user activity, page views and all values by executing a query on each page load, in php.

- Now I am thinking about storing all these as session values and
  ***executing a query at the end of the session***. But, I don't know how I can handle this "end of session" event in php.

I thought about a background process which stores all session values just before the session timeout, but I don't know anything about multi-threading methods in php, even though I've heard some circumvention is possible.

- I would like to **determine if user is inactive without a user
  trigger** (like a page load) and save all the session values at the
  end of session, before the timeout.

This would save some workload on the database engine, in a way like this:
A user views many pages, I increase the value in session, insetead of executing a query like

```
update pageviews set numberofviews=numberofviews+1
```

on each page load.

- question is this: "**How can I handle an end of session event in php
  without a user activity**?"

*Solutions to the actual problem are also appreciated. regardless of the relevance to the question in bold.
(I haven't started writing code on this, my question is not about bug fixing.)*

Possible solutions:

- Storing the data in a mysql table which is a memory type and moving
  records to another table once in a while.
- [Php has a session destroy handler here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

I have found out the [php session handler functioon](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) but documentation doesn't say anything about if it can have null parameters for callback parameters?

Will I lose standard functionality if I enter null parameters for the $callback parameters?

I only want to change the session $destroy event. I need help on this one, now.

Relevant posts:
[RP1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255919/964196)

Comment: what this question has to do with mutlithreading.

Comment: none of the tools from apc, memcache, redis fit you requirement?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really use the session_destroy handler since it's only invoked if you explicitly call session_destroy, which won't happen if the user just closes their browser and ends the session.  Since there is no way of capturing the end of session "event" in that scenario, you'll have to instead do some sort of periodic checking to see if the session has been idle for a given period of time.  The simplest way to do this is create a field in your session that holds the last access time, then create a script which periodically (either via cron or triggered off some other functionality in your PHP scripts) checks that field for all active sessions and, for any which have a timestamp older than xx seconds, run your update query.

Note that in order to do this using standard PHP sessions which are stored on the file system you'll have to actually open the files and parse them directly.  An alternative is to store the sessions in the database but that's probably not what you want to do given the fact you're trying to reduce load on the db.

One other possibility which isn't quite as development-intensive is:

1. Add a last-accessed timestamp to your session
2. Check that timestamp each time you update the session
3. If the timestamp is older than xx seconds run the update query on the db and set the timestamp to the current time.

That way you're only updating the database every so often instead of every page load.  The downside to this approach of course is that unless the last activity on the session corresponds exactly with a time interval which invokes the update function, you may not store the most up-to-date session info in the db.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what the sessions were created for, so what you are trying to achieve isn't possible with session mechanics alone.

With standard PHP sessions your options are somewhat limited and depend on session storage:

1. By default sessions are stored in files. If you disable session garbage collection you can run a cron job that will parse session files older than the time you define. It's not perfect, but by far the simplest. Also file sessions suck - write every request.
2. Sessions in Memcached. With no good method of fetching records older than x and the fact that Memcached will just drop data when it expires not much can be done here.
3. Sessions in DB - you already have an update every request.

So your options with standard sessions are limited at best. My recommendation: replace the standard session with your own, but that means you will no longer be accessing session via $_SESSION and will require you to rewrite a lot of your code.

I have replaced the regular session with a singleton that stores session data in APC/Memcached as well as in DB. Session data is saved in DB only if I request it (`Session::persistentStore($key,$value)`) or if during handling of the request APC/Memcached stored session data indicates it wasn't written for a long enough time. This limits number of writes a lot. 
With this replacement you'd be just forcing session save from DB side: fetch session ids of sessions that haven't been updated for x minutes from db, fetch info from APC/Memcached for each of those and if there is no update info there either (indicating session will end soon) save it to db.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild thought here, you could fire a http request to save your session data on window unload from javascript. The problem is browsers usually stop requests once the page is closed so this request might not even hit the server but I guess it's worth a test.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some workarounds, every solution that you could find to solve this problem will be more inefficient than recording each user activity in each request.

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you trying to solve? I don't see why you *wouldn't* fire an update query to the database every request. It shouldn't take much longer than 0,0001s.

I would most definitely go for the update each request. It's 1 line of code, does not create any excessive load on the database and is much more efficient.

Your proposed method is hard to test, creates unwanted load and might even create global state. You can prevent all that by just going for the conventional solution. Sessions are a (...) when it comes to determining when they 'ended'.

Comment: it's pretty easy to do in asp.net

Comment: Update = write operation. Hard drives have 70-150 iops and when load increases you start to notice that.

Comment: There's tons of queries you need to execute every request, this one is not gonna be the heaviest one.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about a background process which stores all session values
>   just before the session timeout, but I don't know anything about
>   multi-threading methods in php, even though I've heard some
>   circumvention is possible.

you can do this if you are using db based sessions fairly easily.

1. Doesn't require multithreading
2. write a cron job that runs every minute / 5 minutes

   - selects all records about to expire
   - saves them into some other table

the key is using a cron job and not trying to handle the expiration event midstream on an http request

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about delaying statistics writes and session management. Your real problem, I guess, is to avoid per-http-requests writes queries on the database.

Some hints that could be useful for such problems:

1. Be careful with **parallel access on the session**. We usually think the session is only accessed by one process, but that's wrong, let's say for example you are performing a multifile upload with some js opening several ajax request to the server, each process is using the same session. Same thing when you open 10 tabs on the same website with your browser.
2. Adding **update queries** for each request is an **heavy thing**. Select queries are fast and usually using some sort of cache on the SQL side. Update queries are slow, may be rebuilding indexes, and usually implies some cache cleanup on the SQL server. They may also imply a different SQL session if you are using different users on the database for read-only or read-write access.
3. the **session size** shouldn't be too big, as the session must be loaded for each request, and each time you **write** something in your session a **lock** mechanism (because of 1) is set and the data is pushed to the physicial session store (file by default). So session writes are slowing down your process.
4. A NoSQl backend such as **MongoDb** or **Reddit** may be a good place to store per-request statistics, they have the right tools to ensure atomic updates, locks, and may perform really faster than a Relationnal database (but you can check the memory tables performances in the relationnal database also). So you could use theses tools to track activity and avoid SQL updates by using theses backends as the primary target for live statistics. And you could **asynchronously** collect some statictics from theses backends for your database. Now sessions are temporary objects and theses NoSQl backends could also be good **session storages** (if you write your own session storage handlers).

**EDIT:** example of atomic update problems with parallel usage: performing a query asking for increment *counter = counter +1* is the the same as reading a counter, incrementing it and performing an update query *counter = mynewvalue*. The second one is wrong when several process use the same data.

Answer (score 0):

A bit off track, but you could do your own garbage collection.

- use PHP to save the sessions in a directory, preferably tmpfs, with garbage collection disabled.
- write a periodic PHP script to find all session files over 20 minutes old, open them up, write them to database and remove them.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the correct answer. In your situation, the session is not destroyed by the script (=an user action) but when it's old enough to be cleaned up. This garbage collection is usually done with a given chance when *any* PHP script is run. Get your sessions in a separate directory to keep them from "foreign" cleaning and disable the default garbage collection. Then create your own collector that stored the content before cleaning a session. If you want to have it independet from PHP scripts ran by users, than you need a cronjob.