# CodeIgniter - execute function when session expires

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'd like to update my own database when session expires. To do this I modified CodeIgniter's Session file and wrote my own code in sess_destroy(). Everytime the user logouts, sess_destroy() is called. It works correctly as my database gets updated. My problem though is that my database doesn't update when session expires. To test it, I set the sess_expiration in the config.php file to 20 seconds so I wouldn't have to wait long for it to expire. After it does expire, login details that are supposed to be displayed are gone, meaning the session is gone. My database, however, was not updated at all. I've tried inputting code in unset_userdata() and sess_gc() but database still doesn't update.

Suggestions are welcome. Thank you

Comment: see here you can't do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255919/php-session-expire-event

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to call some sort of cron job to regularly scan the database of sessions for expired sessions and purge them or log them etc. Nothing is going to trigger that automatically.