# How to make sure only one administrator is logged using only php and/or basic javascript

Tags: php

I am making a website with no database, but I want to control the admin logs. 
I want only one administrator to be logged at a time.
I have no database to store the accounts

I tried creating a file, but I cannot seem to delete it properly on the disconnection of the admin...
I also tried to look into sessions, but I couldn't fit them properly to my issue.

Here is the code snippet that handles authentification

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" AND !file_exists($location)
    AND isset($_POST['pass']) AND $_POST['pass'] == "PASS"
    AND isset($_POST['pseudo']) AND $_POST['pseudo'] == "ADMIN")
```

tl;dr : How can I store server side that an admin is logged, making impossible for another one can connect?

Comment: _“tl;dr : How can I make sure only one admin is logged at a time?”_ - by storing that info somewhere on the server, so that it is available to all instances of the script. (Know as much as you did before already now? Well then you need to ask a better question, see [ask].)

Comment: you can use php sessions

Comment: You seem to already have answered your question, a file is a valid solution. If you have problems deleting it on logout, it's the code that does that we need to see, and any error/unexpected behaviour you have when you try it.

Comment: @Vishwa no he can't, sessions are relative to 1 instance

Comment: But when to unset the session? I have a disconnect button thant handles clean leaving, but if the user closes the page, wouldn't it make it impossible to reconnect?

Comment: @Kaddath The issue with the file was that I could only delete it with php unlink, however I couldn't make that call on the user closing the page (or at least don't know how)

Comment: @TheSub63 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255919/php-session-expire-event) it may help

Comment: Could you add a listener on the front end for the page being closed (I go to some website where when I try to close the tab an alert dialog pops up to check I meant to do it) which could trigger an Ajax response to delete the file?  I'm not sure how reliable it would be though

Comment: You could use a token. A token is just a difficult to guess random string. When an admin logs in you generate the token, you store it in the session and in a file. You only give access when both match. When another admin logs in, a new token is created, the old file overwritten and the first admin will be locked out. I know this is probably not ideal, but there's no way to check whether the first admin is still using the site. A Javascript listener on the front page is just not reliable enough.

Comment: A question; When you say that only one admin can be logged in at one given moment, does it mean that no one else can log in while an admin is logged in or do you mean that the logged in admin should be kicked out if another admin logs in (which would probably be super annoying for everyone)?

Comment: If an admin is logged, no other admin should be able to log in, only on regular accounts. Another admin cannot kick out the one that is currently working, he has to wait until the first one disconnects (properly by clicking a button or by closing the page)

Comment: Why can't you allow multiple admins at one time? What problem does it create? Perhaps you should focus on solving that problem, because, as you've discovered, what you've asked in this question is very difficult to implement reliably in a web application. It might be better to fix whatever the underlying issue is which caused you to want this requirement

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not deleting the file at all. Instead I would use the file to store a token and a expiration timestamp for the token.

You can then check, if the timestamp is still valid when someone tries to log in. If it is, deny the login. If it is expired, create a new token, save in in the file and the user session and update the timestamp. On each request, make sure the token in the session still matches the token in the file and that the token is not expired. Make sure to lock the file while reading, writing and checking to avoid race conditions.

To keep a user logged in while on the website, you can then send heartbeats to the server, to update the timestamp a few seconds or minutes to the future. The shorter the time you set the timestamp to the future, the earlier a new user can log in after the old one left the page. If the user logs out, you can of course immediately expire the timestamp.